# Codeigniter URI function url_title() how to use

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am using the CodeIgniter framework and I am confused on how to remove %20 from my urls. Below is an example of my code.
Controller - blog
method - show
attribute - this is my blog

```
public function show($blog= null)
    {
    // my attempt to set the uri segment
    $blogName = $this->uri->segment(3, url_title($blog));
    ... //other code
}
```

this doesnt work, I am confused where I implement the url_title('this is my blog') function so that on page load it shows:

/blog/show/this-is-my-blog

do I need to do something in the config/routes.php file?

thank you!

EDIT:

Alright so I found out that url_title() output this20is20my20blog   so I now have this:

```
      $blogUrl = str_replace("%20", "-", $blog);
    $this->uri->segment(3, $blogUrl);
```

but it still returns the URL with %20

Comment: Without the other code displayed (eg., what "returns" the %20's?), it's impossible to know what's happening.  Also, you say that you want it to show "/blog/show/this-is-my-blog", but you didn't specify what the URI is that you've browsed to nor whether or not you are passing the $blog parameter to the show() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the native php function urldecode to remove any characters that get encoded in a url. Spaces in a URL get encoded to `%20` so instead of doing a str_replace just try

```
public function show($blog= null)
{
    // i'm not sure what url_title does so you might have to tweak this a little
    $blogName = $this->uri->segment(3, urldecode(url_title($blog)));
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing the `url_title()` just before you do the `$this->uri->segment();` to ensure it's returning correctly.